# MySQL opposite value (NOT operator)

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a function is MySQL that automatically `UPDATE`s the value to the opposite one (something like `! NOT` operator in php), without fetching the data, changing the value and inserting it again.

Also, if this helps, i need it only for `zeroes` and `ones` if there is any other, simpler way.

```
!0 = 1
!1 = 0
```

Comment: `!` is working in fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56e60/2

Comment: @Biker John I posted my answer just try it work or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For only 0 and 1 you can do

```
UPDATE myTable SET myValue= 1 - myValue    // 1 becomes 0, 0 becomes 1.
```

If you want to include -1 in the scheme as well, you can do

```
UPDATE myTable SET myValue= 1 - ABS(myValue)    // 1 and -1 become 0, 0 becomes 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
UPDATE `your_table` SET `your_boolean_field` = NOT your_boolean_field;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=1-column1
```

If column1 is 1, than it will be 0, because 1-1=0, and if it's 0, then 1-0=1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  for 0 and 1 only

```
UPDATE table_name SET myValue = IF (myValue, 0, 1);
```

Check here [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6907d/2)